# High Pass Filtering and Noise

Tags: fft, power-spectral-density, filtering

I have the following code:

```
sigma_th = 0.08;
ph_noise = sigma_th*randn(1,2^22);
[b,a] = butter(1,4e6/1e9,'high');
ph_noise_out = filter(b, a, ph_noise);
figure(1);
[psd1,w] = pwelch(ph_noise,blackmanharris(2^22/8),[],[],100e9,'onesided');
semilogx(w,10*log10(psd1/2));grid on;
hold on;
[psd2,w] = pwelch(ph_noise_out,blackmanharris(2^22/8),[],[],100e9,'onesided');
semilogx(w,10*log10(psd2/2));grid on;
[psd3,w] = pwelch(ph_noise_out - ph_noise,blackmanharris(2^22/8),[],[],100e9,'onesided');
semilogx(w,10*log10(psd3/2));grid on;
```

Here, I generate a noise signal `ph_noise` and high pass filter the noise using a butterworth filter to get the output `ph_noise_out`.
If I check the power spectral density of the `ph_noise` and `ph_noise_out`, I see that the output spectrum is filtered at low frequencies but is exactly the same at high frequencies. But when I plot the difference between the two noises, I see that the difference falls down as 20dB/dec. Why is the difference falling so slowly? How can I make it fall faster?
PS. The blue curve is the `ph_noise`, orange is the filtered noise `ph_noise_out` and yellow is the power of the difference signal.
[image]

Comment: you should use a faster roll-off ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roll-off )

Comment: But how can I set the roll-off for the difference?

Comment: In Matlab, the first argument of *butter()* is the filter order - increase it?

Comment: It would increase the roll off for the filtered noise but not for the difference signal. The difference still falls at 20dB/dec. I just checked

Comment: If I see correctly, you are calculating a difference in time domain, this is somewhat tricky. Try calculating the spectra seperatly and calculate the difference from those.

Comment: @Max, from the graph it's clear that he's computing the difference from the PSD estimates.

Comment: @dsp_user, the code says something different, does it not? I'm not familiar with Matlab.

Comment: @Max I have to do the difference in time domain because this will be used in another model which I am using. Is there a way to increase the roll off in time domain?

Comment: @dsp_user I am computing the difference of the time domain signals and then computing the PSD of the difference.

Comment: @sarthak, roll-off is a frequency domain parameter and I don't think that you can accurately estimate it by subtracting one time domain signal from another and then doing PSD on the difference signal.  Anyway, I don't understand why you need that yellow curve at all. The red one seems enough as it shows the roll-off clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is the decorrelation due to the varying phase shift between the input and output. See the plot below showing the phase of the OP's high pass filter, and how closely it follows the cancellation when plotted on a log log scale (the higher frequency components of the two signals are better aligned in time and therefore have higher correlation leading to better cancellation).

The correlation between signals vs phase is proportional to the sine of the phase (signals in quadrature are uncorrelated consistent $\sin(\pi/2)=0$. For small angles the sine of the angle is the angle in radians hence we see the close match between the response of the phase and the cancellation of your signal as in your plots.

[image: Angle of Filter vs Frequency]

Due to the small angle, the OP's cancellation signal, assuming perfect amplitude matching, will have a magnitude that is directly proportional to the phase itself in radians between the two signals. Consider the cancellation of two signals with identical magnitude but a difference in phase:

$$y_1= Ae^{j\phi_1}$$
$$y_2= Ae^{j\phi_2}$$

$$y_1-y_2 = Ae^{j\phi_1}- Ae^{j\phi_2} = Ae^{j\phi_1}(1-Ae^{j(\phi_2-\phi_1)})$$
$$= Ae^{j\phi_1}e^{j(\phi_2-\phi_1)/2}(e^{-j(\phi_2-\phi_1)/2}-e^{j(\phi_2-\phi_1)/2})$$
$$ = -Ae^{j\phi_1}e^{j(\phi_2-\phi_1)/2}2j\sin\big((\phi_2-\phi_1)/2\big)$$
$$ = -2Aje^{j(\phi_1+\phi_2)/2}\sin\big((\phi_2-\phi_1)/2\big)$$
$$ = 2Ae^{j(\phi_1+\phi_2-\pi)/2}\sin\big((\phi_2-\phi_1)/2\big)$$

For a small difference angle $\phi_2-\phi_1$, $\sin\big((\phi_2-\phi_1)/2\big) \approx (\phi_2-\phi_1)/2$, so the above cancellation becomes:

$$\approx A(\phi_2-\phi_1)e^{j(\phi_1+\phi_2-\pi)/2}$$

And thus for small angles the magnitude of the cancellation is directly proportional to the difference in phase. And the cancellation ratio as the magnitude of the cancelled signal compared to the magnitude of the input signal would be the difference in phase directly:

$$|y_1-y_2|/|y_1| =| \phi_2-\phi_1|$$

To achieve what the OP is trying to do, the phase response of the filter must be compensated for before doing the subtraction. This would be much easier if a linear phase filter was used instead of the Butterworth filter as the phase compensation of the input signal could then be accomplished with a simple single tap delay. Of course, to completely cancel the signal the amplitudes would need to be exactly matched in the region of cancellation as well.

In practical application even with close matching a finite delay will exist between the two identical signals prior to subtraction, resulting in a high pass response with a cutoff of $1/T$ given a finite delay $T$. With a fixed delay $T$ the lower frequency components much less than $1/T$ in frequency would have a higher cancellation, and the decorrelation will go proportional to $f$ as the frequency approaches $1/T$. Signals much higher than $1/T$ would be decorrelated so would result in a $3$ dB increase as expected for the the sum of two uncorrelated signals.

Comment: @sarthak you also clearly see here the phase dispersion I was referring to with your other question regarding a carrier tracking loop

Answer (score 1):

> I see that the difference falls down as 20dB/dec.

Because you high pass also only has a 20 dB/octave slope. For first order filters the upwards slope of the high pass is symmetrical to the downwards slope of (1 - highpass) other than bilinear distortion. Your difference cannot fall faster than the high pass rises.

> How can I make it fall faster?

You need to increase the filter order. However, in this case you run into time/phase alignment problem that Dan Boschen describes. You either need to use a linear phase FIR filter, using certain types of Butterworth filters with an alignment all passe filter in the "though" pass

Comment: This really has nothing to do with the roll-off of the filter (other than it's impact on group delay) since the cancellation is occurring in the region where the loss of the filter is minimal.